# How to infer the correct value type in URLQueryItem?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string like this:

```
let string = "/somedata&id=123&flag=false&name=david"
```

Then I want to parse the parameters with Swift. My current method is to construct a NSURLComponents with it, then get its queryItems array. Each URLQueryItem has a name and value fields:

```
let urlComponent = NSURLComponents(string: string)
var dict = [String: String]()
let queryItems = urlComponent?.queryItems
for item in queryItems! {
    if item.value != nil {
        dict[item.name] = item.value!
    }
}
```

But the problem is, item.value is ALWAYS String type. I wonder if there's any way to automatically infer the correct data type.

Comment: Generally, every part of the URL component is a string. Since URL is also full string. so the component is also string. You need to cast your id to int.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
let string = "https://test.com/?somedata&id=123&flag=false&name=david"
let urlComponent = NSURLComponents(string: string)
var dict = [String: String]()

if let queryItems = urlComponent?.queryItems{
    for item in queryItems {
        if let value = item.value {
            if let num = Double(value){
                print(num)
            }else if let boolval = Bool(value){
                print(boolval)
            }else{
                print(value)
            }
            dict[item.name] = item.value!
        }
    }
}
```